# node.js - testing to ensure no 'dangling callbacks'

Tags: testing, node.js

I would like my node.js tests to ensure that, once the test is over and `test.finish()` or similar is called, that there is no more code waiting to be run. No more I/O waiting to finish, no more timers waiting to fire, etc. etc.

Is this possible in node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [wrote my own](https://github.com/nornagon/node-zap), which essentially spins up a node instance for each test. If your test leaves a callback dangling, node just won't exit, and the whole test suite hangs instead of exiting early with success (which would be bad!)

Comment: Ok, it's generally Good Practice on S/O to also actually explain what you did (rather than just pointing to a link). Firstly because adding an extra clickthrough is annoying... and also because someday that link may break... thus rendering this answer totally useless. t the very least, it would be nice if you could summarise what you did to solve this... so we know whether it's worth checking out your link :) please :)

Answer (score 1):

When using [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit) each test function keeps running until `test.done()` has been called. Every test function needs to call this. This way you can make sure your callbacks have been executed. I also like to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module to clean up my code(callbacks) a bit.

Comment: That's fine until the test erroneously doesn't call test.done(). Then node just exits and the best you can do is catch process.on('exit') and say that the test suite halted erroneously.

Comment: When I use nodeunit, node does not exit when I don't call test.done()? It just keeps halting..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `test.expect()` at the beginning of each test and `test.done()` at the end of each one? Think of them like begin and end braces.